# Flask & API : Trying to send requests from flask

Tags: python, html, flask

I'm building a login system right now, and I need to send requests from the HTML. For that I use this script:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Login Form</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="static/style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="login-box">
        <h1>INTERKODAS.LT</h1>
            <div class="textbox">
                <i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                <input type="email" placeholder="Email Address" name="email" value="">
            </div>

        <form action="http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/test?" method="POST" target="_blank">

            <div class="textbox">
                <i class="fa fa-lock" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                <input type="password" placeholder="category" name="category" value="">
            </div>

            <input class="btn" type="submit" name="" value="Sign in">

        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="copyright">
            <h4>©™ 2019 Copyright All Rights Reserved</h4>
         </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The thing is that it sents requests, but it doesn't insert any value. For example, when I use the GET Method it does insert a value in the request. How can I insert a value in that link?
The correct post method would be - http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/test?category=computers

BackEnd code (Python) :

```
##================== Requests
async def Handle(request):
    get_time = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%b %y %H.%M:%S")
    object_name = 'Lempa'#request.query['name']
    category = request.query['category']
    print('Category search',category)
    if ' ' in category or len(category) <=2: #Short-Name
        response_obj = {"status" : "error", "message" : "short name","name" : f"{object_name}", "search_time" : f"{get_time}", "category" : f"{category}"}
        return web.Response(text=json.dumps(response_obj), status = 401)
    else:# Success
        # self.item_id, self.item_category, self.item_name, self.item_desc,self.item_ins, self.item_price, self.item_upload_date
        #Scan_Item = LoadItems()
        #itemid, item_category, item_name, item_desc, item_ins, item_price, item_upload = Scan_Item.search_by_category(category)
        Loadinam = LoadItems()
        Loadinam.search_by_category()
        response_obj = {"status" : "ok", "message" : "success","name" : f"{category}", "search_time" : f"{get_time}", "category" : f"{category}", "in_stock" : f"{category}", "price" : f"{category}"}
        content={
            "server": "running",
            "locale": "en",
            "status": "ok",
            "search_time" : f"{get_time}",
            "name": f"{category}",
            "category" : f"{category}",
            "in_stock" : f"{category}",
            "item_id" : f"{category}",
            "price" : f"{category}",
            "item_desc" : f"{category}",
            "item_upload" : f"{category}"
        }
        return web.Response(text=json.dumps(content), status = 200)
```

Comment: Show the backend code.

Comment: @NarasimhaPrasannaHN already